# text extraction project - best tool for extracting only specific rows / items out of a PDF?

Tags: python, ruby, pdf, text, automator

I'm working on a project that is going to extract specified text from a pdf document. I have no experience with this type of extraction. One issue is that we don't just want a dump of all the text in the document. Rather, is there a way to extract only certain fields in the pdf? Is there a notion of pdf templates that could be used for something like this?

I'm trying to use Apple's Automator - this is able to get all the text but not specified text. Ideally, I would like someone in Pages to have for example 30 discreet rows of text and have 20 of those rows be specified as 'catalog item' and have our Automator script take ONLY those twenty lines.

Any ideas on best workflow / extraction tools for this? I would prefer only consumer level items be used such as Apple Pages, Automator, and ruby or python as a scripting language.

thx

**edit #1**
looks like tagged pdf's might be one way to do this - not sure how well supported on Apple Pages this is

Comment: curious why people vote to close?

Comment: Are the PDF documents you want to extract from in tagged-pdf format?

Comment: We could probably choose whether they are tagged or not. These would be documents that end users could produce and not sure how well (or if at all) tagged pdf's are supported. This is a from-scratch solution so any ideas are apprecited.

Comment: If end-users are producing this, does it *need* to be a pdf? This task would be much easier with a plain-text document, a csv file, or practically anything other than a pdf (because pdfs are geared towards visual aesthetics, not information retrieval).

Answer (score 1):

With python, the best choice would probably be [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/). It can extract the coordinates for every text string, so you can work out the rectangles in your form on your own and pick out what falls within them. It's all pretty low level, but PDF is unfortunately a pretty low level format.

Be warned that unless you already know a lot about the structure of PDF, you'll find the API and documentation rather scanty. Look around for usage examples, including here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Origami](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310181914/http://esec-lab.sogeti.com:80/pages/Origami) in **Ruby**, a framework designed to parse, analyze,
and forge PDF documents, or the **Python** equivalent: [Origapy](https://www.decalage.info/python/origapy), a simple Python
interface for the Ruby based Origami.

Comment: thx - I've used Origami but I don't think it handles tagged pdfs

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby you might try [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) for parsing a PDF and accessing both metadata and content. Extracting the specific items your interested in is another story, but how to go about doing that depends highly on what format of data you're expecting.

Comment: thx for answer - agreed about the 'another story'. At this point, we have control of format so we'd like to create the best story for the problem of hand of an automated text extraction system from Apple Pages